# Access HTTP response headers in for flash.net.URLLoader object?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, http-headers, urlloader

Is there a way to access the response headers from an HTTP result when using Flash/Flex's `URLLoader`?

Setting the *request* headers is possible, as is accessing the *response code*, but getting a hold of the actual response headers seems to be conspicuously lacking...

Specifically, I would like to get a hold of the `Last-Modified` response header.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Oops. Answering my own question here, but AIR introduces the [`URLLoader.httpResponseStatus`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#event:httpResponseStatus) event which includes a `responseHeaders` property (plus a `responseURL` property for brownie points).

Thankfully my question was for an AIR application, so that solves my problem. It's still a bit shocking that non-AIR flash/flex applications cannot seem to access the response headers.

Comment: I'm trying to get hold of response header when loading mp3 in sound object (there should come some additional headers). Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, can't tell you off the top of my head - I think more info would help. Be bold and ask a new question, I say. Comment the link here, and I'll try answer.

Comment: It looks like the Flash Player does not get the http response status event. More info here, http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/HTTPStatusEvent.html. If anything has changed still looking for a way to do this.