# How to retrieve the http response headers in a non-AIR application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, http-headers, urlloader

[Access HTTP response headers in for flash.net.URLLoader object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185761/access-http-response-headers-in-for-flash-net-urlloader-object)

I found the above question that seemed to have a solution for an AIR application but not for my non-AIR flex application? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I was reaching a little beyond the abilities of a non-air flash application. I wound up retrieving the headers server side and then using the external interface callback functionality to use what I knew about the headers flex-side.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not possible in native as3 you could parse it yourself. Open a socket connection using the Socket class and connect to the url/domain using port 80.

After you connected you can read out the socket buffer and parse the string to get the response headers.

You can follow the Telnet example on http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-181c51321220efd9d1c-8000.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7cf7 and change the port numbers to 80.